# phpsearch and replace but not duplicate

Tags: php, replace

I would like to use php to replace the word "Dozenten" with "Dozentin" and the word "Dozent" with "Dozenten". The problem now is that "Dozent" occurs in both words. I can't get any further with a str_replace. How can I prevent that I then get something like "Dozentenin"?

Comment: use `preg_replace` with `\b` the `\b` is the boundary anchor that matches the position between a word character. This can resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the [strtr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr) function, this will translate (replace) substrings in your string:

```php
<?php

$s = "Dozenten Dozent Dozent Dozenten";

echo strtr($s, array("Dozenten" => "Dozentin", "Dozent" => "Dozenten"));
```

[Try it online](https://3v4l.org/BHO9n)